# creating app on digital ocean issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I've got a guide which im following [here](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-rails-to-digitalocean-the-hard-way/).

Now this is working perfectly so far, however, I'm up to the part where I need to do the DB migrate and I've ran into this error:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 6 column 1
```

Now I'm thinking it may be because when I did a rake secret it only returned a long number, rather than a key and a token.

Any thoughts/opinions on this?

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have a syntax error in some of your .yml file. `Psych` is a [YAML parsing library](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych)